# Android multithreading and services

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask

I am little bit confused with multithreading in Android.  I am aware we can achieve using `AsyncTask` and `Handler`. Generally when should we implement by extending **Thread Class** in Android? Can anyone give an example that we need to do it only by extending thread class but not with `AsyncTask` or `Handler`.

1. Consider a example app, we have a bouncing ball in an activity(forget the animation part), I need to change the color of the ball every 20 minutes, and I need to get the color code from the server and update the ball UI. Now how can I achieve this ? Can someone explain using `AsyncTask` or `Handler` and also only using Thread Class(without `Asynctask` or `Handler`)?
2. How should I handle downloading large payloads from server using services.

Answer (score 6):

**Thread**

- Long task in general
- Invoke by `thread.start()` method
- Triggered from any thread
- Runs on its own thread
- Manual thread management/code may become difficult to read

**AsyncTask**

- Small task having to communicate with main thread
- Invoke by `execute()` method
- Triggered from main thread
- Runs on worker thread
- Must be executed and created from the main Thread

**Service**

- Task with no UI,but should not use for long Task. Use Thread within service for long Task
- Invoke by `onStartService()`
- Triggered from any Thread
- Runs On Main Thread
- May block main(UI) thread

**IntentService**

- Long task usually no communication with main thread if communication is needed then it is done by Handler or broadcast
- Invoke via Intent
- Triggered from Main Thread (Intent is received on main Thread and worker thread is spawned)
- Runs on separate thread
- Can't run task in parallel and multiple intents are Queued on the same worker thread.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer , can give your view on Bouncing Ball App

Answer (score 0):

An `AsyncTask` is basically a thread. It has 3 callBack methods(main) and the are executed in this order top to bottom:

```
 1. onPreExecute()
 2. doInBackground()
 3. onPostExecute()
 4. onProgressUpdate()
```

The `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` are running on the UI thread and `doInBackground()` is a separate thread as such. If you spawn a thread(not a `AsyncTask`), and try to set a property of a UI element from it, this will raise an exception saying: the original thread(the UI thread) which created the view can only modify it. So only the UI thread has these two properties:

1. Only it can add/modify the UI of the App
2. It cannot be blocked for more than 5 secs(ANR exception)

So to over come both these limitations in one go, we have `AsyncTask`, it can run resource consuming operations(network access, implementing gaming logic etc) in `doInBackground()`, and still provide ability to alter the UI from  `onPreExecute()` and `onPreExecute()`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer , can give your view on Bouncing Ball App

Comment: Get all color codes before the animation starts and save them locally==>Use handler to count 20 mins==> finally get reference of your activity(this), this.runOnUIThread(new runnable())==> here just change the color of your ball.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread`: Use it to separate long running computation from Main Thread ( UI Thread). If you don't need to update UI or send messages back to UI Thread, use it for long running tasks. **But you don't really need to extend Thread** and write your logic by overriding `Thread` methods. But still `HandlerThread` is effective compared to java `Thread`.

`AsyncTask` : it is designed to be a helper class around `Thread` and `Handler` and does not constitute a generic threading framework. `AsyncTasks` should ideally be used for short operations (a few milli seconds at the most). Recommended for 5 milli seconds task execution.

`Service:`  Use it to handle network transactions, play music, perform file I/O, or interact with a content provider, all from the background.

`HandlerThread/Handler`: A `HandlerThread` is effectively a long-running thread that grabs work from a queue, and operates on it. You can use it even to send results back to UI Thread via `Handler` of UI Thread.

Have a look at below posts for more details:

[Asynctask vs Thread vs Services vs Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651489/asynctask-vs-thread-vs-services-vs-loader/46182558#46182558)

[Handler vs AsyncTask vs Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964011/handler-vs-asynctask-vs-thread/45908614#45908614)

[Creating Background Service in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177212/creating-background-service-in-android)

[Android: Toast in a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134683/android-toast-in-a-thread/45922317#45922317)