# What is the better way to handle ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED intent on my app even if the user doesn't using it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to push a notification when a new app installed containing the app name as a title and its content will be its permissions, so how i can implement that even if the my app is closed, my app will support android 6.0 and higher

Comment: Have you looked at [services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177212/creating-background-service-in-android)?

Comment: yes, but when i am closed the app no intents received